# MySQL Table merge / union?

Tags: mysql, merge, union

I have 2 tables. The first one is refreshed daily.(This table has more that 10 columns but 2 of those is relevant) I would like to make a daily statistics from vid (which is a unique id ) and population. New vid ID-s can appear and disappear every day. For example :

1st day :

```
vid population
123 456
124 567
345 1024
```

2nd day :

```
vid population
123 470
124 520
344 100
```

The second table will be the statistics, and i would like the following result :

```
       |--------------------1st day data          
       |       |----------- 2nd day data
vid stat0819 stat0820
123 456      470
124 567      520
344 0        100
345 1024     0
```

Is it possible with one SQL query? I think, the UNION is the key, but I can't figure it out how.

Comment: What table would have the 1st day's data on the 2nd day?  Without storing the 1st day's data somewhere, I don't see how a Union or any query would work.  You need to somehow archive off the history (like add a trigger and another table which contains all the data independent of day and then query it)

Comment: the second table stores it, after refreshing the first table. In a nutshell i would like to store the daily values in the 2nd table.

Comment: To achieve this you would dynamically have to add columns to the second table.  at some point you'd reach the max columns allowed by database. I believe it to be [4096](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html)  what then?  You may be better off using a trigger and having 3 columns in the 2nd table... VID, population and 'Date'  you could then pivot the data or aggregate the results using views etc.  keeping in mind you still couldn't exceed the max columns allowed in a view.

Comment: i add dynamically the new columns before refreshing the tables, and I will delete the first ones (after 1 or 4 weeks, i dont know yet) . But 1 column every day, 4096 column will be enough for 11 years :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this maybe what you are looking for ?

```sql
select tbl1.vid, tbl1.population as tbl1_population, tbl2.population as tbl2_population
from tbl1
left join tbl2 on tbl2.vid = tbl1.vid

union 

select tbl2.vid, tbl1.population as tbl1_population, tbl2.population as tbl2_population
from tbl1
right join tbl2 on tbl2.vid = tbl1.vid;
```

Comment: `left join` is not enough.

Comment: Edited my answer. This should show the correct data